# Can't create a new applicant individual

Tags: contacts

I'm trying to create a new applicant household. The system won't let me save the donor's information. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SE. We would need to know a lot more to help you.  Was this working previously?  Do you get an error message?  What steps are you taking to create the applicant?  The subject says 'applicant individual', the body says 'applicant household': individuals and households are different things and something that works for one may not work for the other.

Comment: Every time I try to create a household or individual account, it shows an error message.

Comment: Under the contacts tab there is an option to add a new applicant.

Comment: What is the error message?  What does in show in the Civi logfile?